# what is the best way to add element to list of dict in python?

Tags: python, database, list, dictionary

i got two list of dict like :

```
a_list = [
       {'key': 1, 'md5': '65d28',  'file_path': '/test/test.gz'}, 
       {'key': 2, 'md5': '800cc9',   'file_path': '/test/test2.gz'}
]

b_list = [
        {'key': 1, 'md5': '65d28', 'is_upload': False}, 
        {'key': 2, 'md5': '800cc9', 'is_upload': True}
]
```

I have to get results like :

```
a_list = [
       {'key': 1, 'md5': '65d28',  'file_path': '/test/test.gz',  'is_upload': False}, 
       {'key': 2, 'md5': '800cc9',   'file_path': '/test/test2.gz',  'is_upload': True}
]
```

what is most  efficient way to do that??

my first code is :

```
    for a in a_list:
        for b in b_list:
            if a['key'] == b['key'] and a['md5'] == b['md5']:
                a['is_upload'] = b['is_upload']
                break
```

But is there a more efficient with out using two loop? cause a_list and b_list may be a long list.

Thank you!

Comment: Are the lists always sorted (.. or you can sort them first)? - in that case you can iterate over both lists at the same time, and pick the one that has the lexically lowest value each time (and if they're identical, merge them to a single dict before inserting). If the same keys are present in both entries, it'll can be just an index lookup in the second list from the idx in the first (i.e. `for idx, element in a_list.enumerate(): ... b_list[idx] .. `

Answer (score 2):

For larger list, you could do:

```
a_dict = {(ai['key'], ai['md5']): ai for ai in a_list}
b_dict = {(bi['key'], bi['md5']): bi for bi in b_list}

result = [{**value, **b_dict.get(key, {})} for key, value in a_dict.items()]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'file_path': '/test/test.gz', 'is_upload': False, 'key': 1, 'md5': '65d28'},
 {'file_path': '/test/test2.gz', 'is_upload': True, 'key': 2, 'md5': '800cc9'}]
```

If you want to modify `a_list` *in-place*, do:

```
b_dict = {(bi['key'], bi['md5']): bi for bi in b_list}


for d in a_list:
    d.update(b_dict.get((d['key'], d['md5']), {}))

print(a_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **efficient** code (with **one-loop**):

```py
for i in range(len(a_list)):
    if a_list[i]['key'] == b_list[i]['key'] and a_list[i]['md5'] == b_list[i]['md5']:
        a_list[i]['is_upload'] = b_list[i]['is_upload']
```

Output:

```py
a_list = [{'key': 1, 'md5': '65d28', 'file_path': '/test/test.gz', 'is_upload': False},
          {'key': 2, 'md5': '800cc9', 'file_path': '/test/test2.gz', 'is_upload': True}]
```